# Program didnt exit/terminated correctly (CS50 Speller)

Tags: c, dictionary, pointers, hash, cs50

The program runs a spellcheck on a text paired with a given dictionary(CS50: Pset5 Speller). The dictionary file is in form of a txt file, which is loaded into memory in the form of a hash table.

The check function takes an argument of a word that is read from the text file. the word is hashed and compared to any elements exist in a given individual hash table. If a word exist it returns true, else false.

The Hash is hashing any given word, while Load function is loading words from the dictionary to corresponding hash index of the word in the hash table. Load Function takes a pointer to the dictionary as an argument.

Size function is measuring the size of the dictionary by pointing to existing hash table.

Unload function reiterates over each possible index of the hash table while simultaneously calling for ClearNodes which checks for contents in the linked list that is connected to the hash table.

I've tried resizing the texts and dictionaries to smaller sizes, and also i tried to place my breakpoint before and after individual function is called (since somehow placing the breakpoint after `main() loads the dictionary` and `Finished checking all the words in a given text` , then in the debugger manually pressing `step-over` until `main()` is finished, managed to make the program terminated normally). With smaller sizes dictionary and texts i didnt found any resemblance that causes the function to not return a value. Bear in mind the unload function is assume to always return true at this point and it isnt finished.

[Minimum Reproducible Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jfj_SndsYf2r-d-8jeQwq8ZIpjsUmL_F/view?usp=sharing)

Help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>


#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 17576;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //Create Word Hash Value
    int WordHashIndex = hash(word);
    node *Temp = table[WordHashIndex];

    //Jump to Hash Index
    while(Temp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(Temp -> word, word) != 0)
        {
            Temp = Temp -> next;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    if(word[1] == '\0')
    {
        return (toupper(word[0]) - 65);
    }
    else if(word[2] == '\0')
    {
        return ((toupper(word[0]) - 65) + ((((toupper(word[1]) - 65) * 26) > -1) ? ((toupper(word[1]) - 65) * 26) : 0));
    }
    else
    {
        return ((toupper(word[0]) - 65) + ((((toupper(word[1]) - 65) * 26) > -1) ? ((toupper(word[1]) - 65) * 26) : 0) + ((((toupper(word[2]) - 65) * 676) > -1) ? ((toupper(word[2]) - 65) * 676) : 0));
    }
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    int HashedIndex = 0;
    char TempWord[LENGTH + 1];
    int CharLengthCounter = 0;

    FILE *LoadedDictionary = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(LoadedDictionary == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while(fscanf(LoadedDictionary, "%s", TempWord) != EOF)
    {
        HashedIndex = hash(TempWord);
        node *TempNode = NULL;

        //Jump To HashedIndex
        if(table[HashedIndex] != NULL)
        {
            TempNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            TempNode -> next = table[HashedIndex] -> next;
            table[HashedIndex] -> next = TempNode;
            strcpy(TempNode -> word, TempWord);

        }
        else
        {
            TempNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            table[HashedIndex] = TempNode;
            strcpy(table[HashedIndex] -> word, TempWord);
        }
    }

    if(LoadedDictionary != NULL)
    {
        free(LoadedDictionary);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    node *Temp;
    int DictSize = 0;

    for(int Counter = 0; Counter < N; Counter++)
    {
        Temp = table[Counter];
        if(Temp != NULL)
        {
            DictSize++;
            while(Temp -> next != NULL)
            {
                Temp = Temp -> next;
                DictSize++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(DictSize != 0)
    {
        return DictSize;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Check Node Data and Length Inside Each Table
bool ClearNodes(node *CurrentIndex)
{
    if(CurrentIndex != NULL)
    {
        if(CurrentIndex -> next != NULL)
        {
            if(ClearNodes(CurrentIndex -> next))
            {
                free(CurrentIndex);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free(CurrentIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    int TableElementsCheck = 0;

    for(int Counter = 0; Counter < N; Counter++)
    {
        ClearNodes(table[Counter]);
    }

        return true;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre] of the problem. Your posted code is incomplete, as it does not include a function `main` and it references the header file `dictionary.h`, whose contents you have not posted. Also, you are not providing any sample input which reproduces the error.

Comment: Side note: Your code would be easier to read if you wrote `return (toupper(word[0]) - 'A');` instead of `return (toupper(word[0]) - 65);`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks for the advice. Forgive me if adding those files makes it more cluttered than it already is.

Comment: `"(since somehow manually step over the codes in debugger casuse[sic] the program to terminate)"` -- Are you sure you did not confuse "step over" with "step out"? Some debuggers have a feature that allows you to continue running until the function returns, and I believe it is often called "step out". If you use that feature in `main`, then this will of course run your program until it terminates. Which debugger are you using? Is it one provided by CS50?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel **since somehow manually step over the codes in debugger casuse the program to terminate** what I meant by that line, when the breakpoint is placed after ```load() function``` and after ```checking the word from the text (check function)```, if you manually press step over until main is finished, the program somehow terminated normally. My mistake i'll fix it.

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 17576;`  an `node *table[N];` this only works on a C++ compiler  suggest: `#define N 17576`  otherwise a C compiler outputs:  *untitled.c:23:7: error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has at least the following bugs in the function `load`:

The following block is wrong:

```
else
{
    TempNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    table[HashedIndex] = TempNode;
    strcpy(table[HashedIndex] -> word, TempWord);
}
```

You are forgetting to set `TempNode->next` to `NULL`.

Also, the line

```
free(LoadedDictionary);
```

is wrong. You should call `fclose` instead of `free` on a `FILE *` returned by the function `fopen`.

After fixing these bugs, the output appears correct:

```
MISSPELLED WORDS

A
is
not
a
```

This output is correct because those words do not exist in the dictionary that you provided. The words `cat` and `caterpillar` were not printed as wrong, because they were in the dictionary.